# Getting the services/receivers of an Android App

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin

For example: please take a look at this App: [Disable Service](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wq.disableservice&hl=en)

I am trying to figure out how to find the receivers/services of all apps and disable them.

Things I've tried so far:

```
foreach (var item in PackageManager.GetInstalledApplications
             (new Android.Content.PM.PackageInfoFlags()))
{
    var context = CreatePackageContext(
                      item.PackageName, PackageContextFlags.IgnoreSecurity);
    Console.WriteLine(context.PackageName);
    // contex.PackageManager.GetReceiverInfo()
    // contex.PackageManager.QueryIntentServices
}
```

I'm able to get all the packages but confused on getting their services/intent.

Thanks.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it to work now. I am able to get the items. Any idea on how to enable/disable them?

Comment: nope,  my common sense tells me it's impossible

Comment: No way it can be impossible. There are tons of apps that does this. One of them being the "Disable Service" link I provided above. Hmmm.

Comment: oh,  it needs root,  so my common sense was right....

Comment: yay for common sense :D. I'll try to improve mine and figure out how to do this, with root.

Comment: Just to clarify, to modify other apps values, they have to define them as MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE, otherwise you have no access to them. If apps offer their settings, it's mostly just MODE_WORLD_READABLE, so you can only read them, s. http://chrisrisner.com/Accessing-the-Shared-Preferences-of-a-Different-Application-in-Android